# Error whenever I try to add image to my Django project

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, django

[image: This is the screenshot error message I'm getting]The idea of the *base.html* is not to be repeating some codes that I will need in almost all of the pages. I can easily put `{% extends 'homepage/base.html' %}` on every page I need it.

Check out my base.html below.

```html
1. (base.html) 
    

        {% load static %}
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <!-- Required meta tags -->
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

          <!--fonts-->
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
   family=Comfortaa:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Niconne&family=Satisfy&display=swap" 
   rel="stylesheet">   

          <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
          <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
   rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
   +0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/css/styles.css' %}">

          {% if title %}
            <title>Amal Restaurant - {{ title }}</title>
          {% else %}
            <title>Amal Restaurant</title>
          {% endif %}
        </head>
        <body>
          {% block content %}

          {% endblock content %}

          <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
          <!--
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          -->
          <!--jquery cdn-->
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
   integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
          </script>
          <!--local js files-->
          <script src="{% static 'homepage/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
          <script src="{% static 'homepage/js/main.js' %}"></script>

       </body>
       </html>
```

This is the index.html where I have `{% extends 'homepage/base.html' %}`. Everything is working well except for my images.

Check out my index.html below.

```html
2. (index.html)

        {% extends 'homepage/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
   <header class="header">
       <div id="logo">
           <img src="images/logo-white.png" alt="logo">
       </div>
       <div id="nav-bar">
           <ul>
               <li id="delivery"><a href="#">Food deliveries</a></li>
               <li id="works"><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
               <li id="cities"><a href="#">Our cities</a></li>
               <li id="sign"><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>      
           </ul>
       </div>

       <div class="header-text">
           <h1 id="header-text-main">
               <span id="header-text-primary">Goodbye junk food.</span>
               <span id="header-text-secondary">Hello super healthy meals.</span>
           </h1>
           <div class="header-buttons">
               <span id="hungry">I'm hungry</span>
               <span id="more">Place Your Order</span>
           </div>
       </div>
   </header>
   <section class="main">
       <h2 class="headers">Get food fast — not fast food</h2>
       <p class="texts">
           Hello, we're Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you're always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we're really good at it, we promise!
       </p>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
                   <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
                   <p>
                       Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
                   </p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
                   <h3>Ready in 20 minutes</h3>
                   <p>
                       You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.
                   </p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></i>
                   <h3>100% organic</h3>
                   <p>
                       All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
                   </p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i>
                   <h3>Order anything</h3>
                   <p>
                       We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
                   </p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>

   <section class="gallery">
       <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">
               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                   <a href="#" class="mb-4 h-100">
                   <img src="{% static 'homepage/images/amala.jpeg' %}">
                   </a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                   <a href="#" class="mb-4 h-100">
                   <img src="{% static 'homepage/images/semo.jpeg' %}">
                   </a>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                   <a href="#" class="mb-4 h-100">
                   <img src="{% static 'homepage/images/jollof.jpeg' %}">
                   </a>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>

{% endblock content %}
```

In my static directory I have another directory homepage, inside the homepage is where I have the images, CSS and js directories.

Like this: `static/homepage/images`

Comment: What error are you "having"? Please paste it into your post.

Comment: i just added the screenshot of the error message, please check it.. thank you.

Comment: Try checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700097/how-to-point-correctly-to-static-image-in-django

Comment: `{% load static %}` you need to write it in `index.html` _too_ (the parent template loading it does not mean the child template can use it directly) because you use the tag there. Write it directly below `{% extends 'homepage/base.html' %}`

Comment: thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat it worked perfectly... i almost broke my laptop... xD

Comment: thank you all for the help, @AbdulAzizBarkat's help solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `{% load static %}` in `index.html` as well.