# Rendering a images in HTML template using django template tags

Tags: html, django, templates

Want to render images in a HTML template using Django template tags.

I tried the following template tags inside the HTML files. I rendered HTML template passing with the list of images as shown below. I have also includes load_staitc command at the top of the template.

```
{% for image_url in image_urls %}
        <img src="{{ image_url }}" alt="Image">
    {% endfor %}
```

Following is the my view.py method.

```
def image_gallery(request):
    image_urls = ['images\filter.JPG', 'images\logo1.png', 'images\profile1.jpg']
    return render(request, 'myapp/image_gallery.html', {'image_urls': image_urls})
```

Images are not being loaded in the HTML template. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Are the images contained in a folder in the project? If yes, in what folder?

If no, are they hosted somewhere else, like AWS?

Comment: Yes. The images are inside the static/images folder within the project.

Comment: Perhaps this question might help in your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700097/how-to-point-correctly-to-static-image-in-django